# writing the composition of map and fold_left as a fold_left

Tags: types, functional-programming, ocaml, theory

Given

```
f : A -> B -> A
g : A -> A
l : list B
acc : list A
```

how can I write `(map g (fold_left f l acc))` as a `fold_left` ?

I tried writing something like `(fold_left (fun x => (g (f x)) l (map g acc))`, but it does not seem to type-check....

Comment: Your first line of code `(map g (fold_left f l acc))` isn't consistent with the type constraints you gave. Typing it says f should be of type `'a list -> 'b -> 'a list`.

Comment: Please try to use the OCaml type notation when asking about OCaml programming.

Answer (score 2):

You write `fold_left f l acc`, but the arguments of a left fold are supposed to be `fold_left f acc l`. This could be your problem.